# Adding annotations to a map from custom contacts group

Tags: iphone

How can I add annotations of all the contacts in my custom group, in a mapview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn two APIs:

- The Address Book
- The MKMapView and Friends.

Make a start with the address book. There are calls to open the address book, find groups and iterate over group entries. When you have that, you can use that information to create Map Annotations.

Show some code here if you get stuck.